# Python Telegram У меня есть файл с id юзеров хочу сделать рассылку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть файл с id юзеров(из файла кодом достаю в массив) хочу сделать рассылку, но при первом юзере попавшем в рассылку который удалил бот весь цикл сбивается и останавливается. как можно пропустить пользователя из за которого будет ошибка и делать рассылку дальше. использую библиотеку Telebot

Comment: Используйте в коде при поллинге `polling(none_stop=True)`, бот не будет прекращать работу при ошибках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью обработки исключений:

```
        try:
            bot.send_message(<chat.id>, <требуемое сообщение>)
            bot.send_message(<chat.id>, <требуемое сообщение>)
        except:
            print('Не удалось отправить сообщению пользователю :', <user_id>)
```

Comment: Уже сам справился, как раз таким методом, всеравно спасибо)